# Start process after specific other processes finished using Python's multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I have a set of processes, where some of these require others processes in the set to finish first. How can I check if the specified processes are finished successfully?

I tried using `multiprocessing.Queue`, but I don't know how to check the content of queue. I am also not sure if this is the correct way to do it:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def print_name(queue, name):
    print(name)
    queue.put(name)


def main():
    order = [{'name': 'procA', 'requires': []},
             {'name': 'procB', 'requires': []},
             {'name': 'procC', 'requires': ['procB']},
             {'name': 'procD', 'requires': ['procA', 'procC']}]
    
    queue = Queue()
    procs = [Process(target=print_name, args=(queue, item['name'])) for item in order]
    
    for item, proc in zip(order, procs):
        if len(item['requires']) == 0:
            proc.start()
        else:
            if all([require in queue for require in item['requires']]):  # I need syntax for "require in queue"
                proc.start()
    
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: 1. You can receive the error with: `proc.start(); proc.join(); if proc.exception: error, traceback = proc.exception;` 2. You need to write the logic for `procC` to `.start()` when `procB` finishes with `.join()`. However you are running `proc.join()` at the very end and for everyone at once.

Comment: @TinNguyen I dind't quite understand the first point. Can I check if a specific process finished with that?